# Add Content in a foreach

Tags: powershell

im trying to write a simple script searches for matches in the folders (see code) and adding the result in a simple .csv. So i can check the overall situation. It should also remove the identical file from the open's folder. Removing the data from the csv is not necessary since i can filter with excel easily :)

The forEach is seems to work but i think im on the wrong way...

```
$open = Get-ChildItem "C:\open" -Filter *.pdf
$closed = Get-ChildItem "C:\closed" -Filter *.pdf
$archive = Get-ChildItem "C:\archive" -Filter *.pdf

foreach($pdf in $open.Name) {

    if ($pdf -eq $archive.Name) {
        Add-Content -Path "C:\log.csv" -Value $pdf.Name, archive
    }
    elseif ($pdf -eq $closed.Name) {
        Add-Content -Path "C:\log.csv" -Value $pdf.Name, closed
        #Here i want to remove the pdf from the open folder
        #another if method?
    }
    else {
        Add-Content -Path "C:\log.csv" -Value $pdf.Name, open 
    }
}
```

Bump, still need help :(

Comment: You probably want to use the `-in` operator, rather than `-eq`

Answer (score 0):

Two things you'll want to change:

Don't use `-eq` to test for collection containment, use `-in` or `-contains` instead:

```
$open = Get-ChildItem "C:\open" -Filter *.pdf
$closed = Get-ChildItem "C:\closed" -Filter *.pdf
$archive = Get-ChildItem "C:\archive" -Filter *.pdf

foreach($pdf in $open.Name) {
    if ($pdf -in $archive.Name) {
        Add-Content -Path "C:\log.csv" -Value $pdf.Name, archive
    }
    elseif ($pdf -in $closed.Name) {
        Add-Content -Path "C:\log.csv" -Value $pdf.Name, closed
    }
    else {
        Add-Content -Path "C:\log.csv" -Value $pdf.Name, open 
    }
}
```

To remove the files in `$open` when encountered in `$closed`, use `Remove-Item`:

```
elseif ($pdf -in $closed.Name) {
    Add-Content -Path "C:\log.csv" -Value $pdf.Name, closed
    $openPath = Join-Path "C:\open" -ChildPath $pdf 
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $openPath -Force
}
```